# What's a normal state?

Tags: functional-analysis

The wikipedia page of states in functional analysis says that:

A state $\tau $ is called normal, iff for every monotone, increasing net $H_{\alpha }$ of operators with upper bound $H$, $\tau (H_{\alpha })$ converges to $\tau (H)$.

However, it seems obvious that we would either need $H_{\alpha}$ to converge to $H$ (not just be an upper bound), or say that $\tau(H)$ is an upper bound for $\tau(H_{\alpha})$. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: States are continuous, so $H_\alpha\to H$ would imply $\tau(H_\alpha)\to\tau(H)$ for every state $\tau$, not just the normal ones. I would check your text, it is possible when they say "with upper bound" they mean "with least upper bound". (Also your second possible interpretation holds for any state by monotonicity of states.)

Comment: @s.harp How then would I go about proving that a vector state is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every bounded, increasing net $(x_\gamma)$ of self-adjoint operators converges **strongly** (not in norm) to some $x$, which we typically write as $x=\sup x_\lambda$.  A state $\tau$ is called normal if $\tau(\sup x_\lambda)=\sup\tau(x_\lambda)$

Comment: I would recommend reading a book on operator algebras to learn about states, that wiki page is awful.